# MATLAB - adding plot to another plot after loop, more sophisticatedly

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour, scatter

i have a problem and i hope that i will find help there.
This is my example code. Its only part of my algorithm. For imagine, how the point are moving, during the equations, i need show contour of function with two variables and into the points. Becase i have more difficult function than parabolic function, so the equations are too long than i need. For this reason i move contour ploting before the loop. But i have problem. I need show countour always and points only for i-loop and my solution doesnt work. Please help me!

```
[R S] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5, -5:0.1:5);

figure
contour(R, S, R.^2 + S.^2, 5);
axis([-5,5,-5,5])
axis square
hold on

for i=1:50
    a = 0;
    b = 1:2
    B = repmat(b,5,1)
    A = unifrnd(a,B)
    x = A(1:5,1);
    y = A(1:5,2);

    scatter(x,y,'fill')
    hold off
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the handle to your `scatter` plot and simply update the `XData` and `YData` properties of it rather than destroying the plot objects every time

```
[R S] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5, -5:0.1:5);

figure
contour(R, S, R.^2 + S.^2, 5);
axis([-5,5,-5,5])
axis square
hold on

% Create a scatter plot and store the graphics handle so we can update later
hscatter = scatter(NaN, NaN, 'fill');

for i=1:50
    a = 0;
    b = 1:2
    B = repmat(b,5,1)
    A = unifrnd(a,B)
    x = A(1:5,1);
    y = A(1:5,2);

    % Update the X and Y positions of the scatter plot
    set(hscatter, 'XData', x, 'YData', y);

    pause(0.5)
end
```